# Unable to get CalendarTrigger Enabled status

Tags: powershell

Unable to get CalendarTrigger Enabled status using below powershell script with admin access.

```
$TaskXMLObj = [xml]$task.Xml
$CalTriggers = $TaskXMLObj.Task.Triggers.CalendarTrigger
$TaskTriggerArray = @()
  
ForEach ($CalTrigger in $CalTriggers) { 
    $obj= New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $obj| Add-Member -Name 'Enabled' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $CalTrigger.Enabled }
```

The above script doesn't return status for Enabled.
Below is the output from when export schedule task showing Enabled status.

```
<Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2023-05-25T06:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByWeek>
        <DaysOfWeek>
          <Monday />
          <Tuesday />
          <Wednesday />
          <Thursday />
          <Friday />
          <Saturday />
        </DaysOfWeek>
        <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
      </ScheduleByWeek>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
```